# Using mod_rewrite to hide actual URLs

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a php website and I'm using `mod_rewrite` to redirect all of the URL requests. Suppose I have a `product.php` script and I have a rule for it:

```
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+).*/?$ product.php?pid=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+).*/?$ category.php?cid=$1 [L,NC]
```

So far, this works great and when the user types: `http://www.mysite.com/product/1` the page with the actual URL of `http:/www.mysite.com/product.php?pid=1` will be shown to him.

However, I want to force the user to access my site, exclusively from the rules that I have provided. By that, I mean when the user types `http:/www.mysite.com/something` or even some correct URL like `http:/www.mysite.com/product.php?pid=1` he should be redirected to the 404 error page. This can be a custom script or apache's default 404 page.

Is that possible?

EDIT: As requested, I post my entire .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes

RewriteEngine on    
RewriteBase /websitename
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+).*/?$ product.php?pid=$1 [L,NC] 
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+).*/?$ category.php?cid=$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add a catch all as the last possible rewrite and map it to 404.php (or whatever you wan't).

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 404.php?attempt=$1 [L,NC]
```

Just place this in the bottom of your rewrites.

**EDIT:**

I tested this out myself (i usually don't use rewrites this way):

```
RewriteEngine on    

RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+).*/?$ product.php?pid=$1 [L] 
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+).*/?$ category.php?cid=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 404.php?attempt=$1 [L]
```

And also found that the 404 would be hit everytime. Apparently this is expected behaviour of  .htaccess. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3642271/603184)

So turns out you need it to stop matching when it hits product/category.php, this can be accomplished via adding:

```
RewriteRule ^category.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^product.php$ - [L]
```

Before the 404 redirect. Resulting in:

```
RewriteEngine on    

RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+).*/?$ product.php?pid=$1 [L] 
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+).*/?$ category.php?cid=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^category.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^product.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 404.php?attempt=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I've tried it before. It just redirects ALL of my URLs to this page, even though I have the L flag for all of my rules.

Comment: That's strange, it usually works perfectly for me. Can you show us the entire set of RewriteRules?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the question :D